# Setting up default pylint config.rc file in Windows

Tags: python, windows, pylint

I'm using Pylint under Windows, and it's not reading my pylint-config.rc file.
Is there a way to set up a default .rc file for Python within windows so that I don't have to keep typing it into the command line?
Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't have a windows box at hand to test, but the code uses `os.path.expanduser('~')` to find the current user's home directory, and looks for a file calle `.pylintrc` in that directory.

According to the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=expanduser#os.path.expanduser), on Windows, `expanduser` uses HOME and USERPROFILE if set, otherwise a combination of HOMEPATH and HOMEDRIVE. So my advice is to check in a Python interactive session what the following script outputs:

```
import os
print os.path.expanduser('~')
```

and put the configuration file as `.pylintrc` in that folder.

Alternatively, if you want to use different configuration files on a per project basis, you should know that if there is a file called `pylintrc` (without a leading dot) in the current working directory, then Pylint will use this one. If there is a file called `__init__.py` in the current working directory, Pylint will look in the parent directory until there is no such file and then look for a `pylintrc` configuration file. This is done so that you can maintain a per project config file together with you source code, and lauch Pylint from any directory in your source tree.

Comment: Thank you!  I primarily made this question to store some information that I'm tired of googling, but it's always good to learn something as well.

Answer (score 8):

Since creating a file beginning with a dot is not allowed from Windows file explorer, you can create a template using:

```
pylint --generate-rcfile > .pylintrc
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible ways to do this.  One way is to edit the file `C:\Python\Scripts\pylint.bat` changing the line

```
python "%~dpn0" %*
```

to

```
python "%~dpn0" %* --rcfile="C:\path\to\pylint.rc"
```

Another way is to go to add an environment variable.  Do this by going to `Start->Control Panel->System` then going to the `Advanced` tab and clicking `Environment Variables`.  Then click `New` and create a variable named PYLINTRC with the value of `C:\path\to\pylint.rc`.